# How to access kotlin pojo in java class

Tags: java, kotlin, pojo, kotlin-android-extensions

```
class Example {

    @SerializedName("foo")
    @Expose
    var foo: String? = null
    @SerializedName("bar")
    @Expose
    var bar: String? = null
    @SerializedName("baz")
    @Expose
    var baz: String? = null
}
```

How to access kotlin pojo class properties in java class

Answer (score 0):

We can access it as given below

```
    Example example = new Example();
    example.setBar("");
    example.setBaz("");
    example.setFoo("");
    example.getBar();
    example.getBaz();
    example.getFoo();
```